# Loading an iframe by removing the content security policy, x-frame-options using chrome extension is failing to load in chrome version 85

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have got a chrome extension to load another websites in my website using iframe. So for loading another website which has content security policy and x-frame-options to same orgin, I have a removed these properties from the response headers using the below code in background.js

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener((info) => {
  const headers = info.responseHeaders.filter((header) => {
    const headerName = header.name.toLowerCase();
    return !(headerName === 'x-frame-options' || headerName === 'frame-options'
      || headerName === 'content-security-policy');
  });

  return { responseHeaders: headers };
},
{ urls: ['*://*/*'], types: ['sub_frame'] },
['blocking', 'responseHeaders']);
```

It was working fine for me for the last one year. But after updating to the latest version of chrome - chrome 85 (85.0.4183.83 and 85.0.4183.102) some websites are not loading for some machines. I'm not sure the issue is because of the chrome version or any other chrome settings. It would be very helpful for me if anyone have a solution or any clue to this question

Comment: Try adding 'extraHeaders'  to the last array in your code.

Comment: @wOxxOm do you have any idea why it is working on some machines and not working on others without 'extraHeaders'?

Comment: I don't know. Probably a bug in Chrome. Moreover, the extraHeaders shouldn't make any difference in this case according to the documentation.

Comment: This used to work up until chrome 85. Now it longer works on Linux OS. Are you finding the same? There are other extension that do what you want (Xframe assasin and Ignore X-frame Headers). I tried both with no luck (I'm on ubuntu 14).